# Choosing any CookieSpec removes all cookies in request

Tags: java, cookies, session-cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a problem I can't seem to grasp.
My relevant code is

```
final Builder requestConfigBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
...
final HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
clientBuilder.setDefaultCookieStore();
clientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfigBuilder.build());
...
```

If I use this client I get from my builder, I can see all cookies being sent in my request as I would expect.
However, adding a cookie spec, like this:

```
final Builder requestConfigBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
...
requestConfigBuilder.setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.DEFAULT);  //this causes problems 
final HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
clientBuilder.setDefaultCookieStore(someCookieStoreVariable);
clientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfigBuilder.build());
...
```

I see no cookies being sent in my request. The result is the same no matter which spec I choose from CookieSpecs.

Am I misunderstanding or misusing this, why doesn't this work? Is there some problem with me setting another cookiestore? I do need it for future references so it has to stay.

Comment: Please post wire logs of both sessions http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html

Answer (score 2):

Check whether cookie domain and path are set properly.